# Error trying to install graphlab

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, graphlab

When i try to import graphlab, i get ImportError.  I'm on a macbook using OSX Yosemite 10.10.4. I do have anaconda but my envs folder is empty.  Based on some research, i tried using conda config --add create_default_packages graphlab-create.  But this didn't do anything. So, i tried

```
pip install graphlab-create --no-cache-dir

Collecting graphlab-create
  Downloading GraphLab-Create-1.6.1.tar.gz (39.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.9MB 136kB/s
```

This is the complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/f4/wdrwxpcj0x95cdhkx5qpfbvr0000gp/T/pip-build-k0zi9aqh/graphlab-create/setup.py", line 87
    print ""
           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/f4/wdrwxpcj0x95cdhkx5qpfbvr0000gp/T/pip-build-k0zi9aqh/graphlab-create
```

It seemed to go through fine and download 100% but then got above error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to use Python 3 to install. Try to install it using Python 2.7.X. It worked for me!

Comment: thanks. will try that. is there an easy way to downgrade?  do i need to remove and then install earlier version?